# Maximum likelihood estimation with uniform distribution in R leads to absurd result

Tags: r, statistics, mle

I want to use the `mle` function to get estimates of `a` and `b` in a `Unif(a,b)` distribution. But I get absurd estimates nowhere close to 1 and 3.

```
library(stats4)
set.seed(20161208)

N <- 100
c <- runif(N, 1, 3)
LL <- function(min, max) {
  R <- runif(100, min, max)
  suppressWarnings((-sum(log(R))))
  }
mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(min = 1, max = 3), method = "BFGS",
    lower = c(-Inf, 0), upper = c(Inf, Inf))
```

I got:

```
Call:
mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(min = 1, max = 3), method = "BFGS")

Coefficients:
     min      max 
150.8114 503.6586
```

Any ideas of what's going on? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you include the names of the libraries that you are using? `mle` is not a base R function.

Comment: Is `LL` supposed to be your log likelihood function? Because `runif` absolutely shouldn't be in your log-likelihood function.

Comment: @lmo: library(stat4)

Comment: @Dason: well, this is how I understood the mle function in R. Am I doing this wrong? Another thing is that the code works fine for other distributions like Poisson and gamma.

Comment: Are you using rpois and rgamma in your likelihood functions for those distributions?

Comment: @Dason: yes, I am.

Comment: @Lola - yeah you're doing it waayyyyyy wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I would first point out where your code is wrong.**

1. You need `dunif` not `runif`. You may define:

   ```
   LL <- function (a, b) -sum(dunif(x, a, b, log.p = TRUE))
   ```

   In my code below I did not use `dunif`, as the density is just `1 / (b - a)` so I wrote it directly.
2. **You are generating samples inside objective function.** For `U[a,b]` this is OK as its density is free of `x`. But for other distributions the objective function changes at each iteration.
3. With box constraints, you need `method = "L-BFGS-B"`, not the ordinary `"BFGS"`. And you are not using the right constraints.

---

Now in more depth...

For a length-`n` sample vector `x` from `U[a, b]`, the likelihood is `(b - a) ^ (-n)`, and negative-log-likelihood is `n * log(b - a)`. Obviously the MLE are `a = min(x)` and `b = max(x)`.

Numerical optimization is completely unnecessary, and is in fact impossible without constraints. Look at the gradient vector:

```
( n / (a - b), n / (b - a) )
```

The partial derivative w.r.t. `a` / `b` is always negative / positive and can't be 0.

Numerical approach becomes feasible when we impose box constraints: `-Inf < a <= min(x)` and `max(x) <= b < Inf`. We know for sure that iteration terminates at the boundary.

My code below uses both `optim` and `mle`. Note `mle` will fail, when it inverts Hessian matrix, as it is singular:

```
-(b - a) ^ 2    (b - a) ^ 2
 (b - a) ^ 2   -(b - a) ^ 2
```

Code:

```
## 100 samples
set.seed(20161208); x <- runif(100, 1, 3)
# range(x)
# [1] 1.026776 2.984544

## using `optim`
nll <- function (par) log(par[2] - par[1])  ## objective function
gr_nll <- function (par) c(-1, 1) / diff(par)  ## gradient function
optim(par = c(0,4), fn = nll, gr = gr_nll, method = "L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(-Inf, max(x)), upper = c(min(x), Inf), hessian = TRUE)
#$par
#[1] 1.026776 2.984544  ## <- reaches boundary!
#
# ...
#
#$hessian  ## <- indeed singular!!
#           [,1]       [,2]
#[1,] -0.2609022  0.2609022
#[2,]  0.2609022 -0.2609022

## using `stats4::mle`
library(stats4)
nll. <- function (a, b) log(b - a)
mle(minuslogl = nll., start = list(a = 0, b = 4), method = "L-BFGS-B",
    lower = c(-Inf, max(x)), upper = c(min(x), Inf))
#Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) : 
#  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[2,2] = 0
```